# WMB HTTP Input Node timeout

Tags: websphere, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus

Am facing an issue with HTTP Input node on production environment. My flow looks like below

HTTP Input Node --> Compute Node(Split Message) --> RCD (Validation and send failure message to Error queues) --> Collector Node(Collect message based on Header) --> Compute Node(Structure the message) --> Soap Envelope --> HTTP Request Node (to other HTTP endpoint flow).

This setup works perfectly fine on lower environment without any issues. However in production once the traffic start flowing, HTTP Input port become unresponsive(basically not accessible) and requests are timed out.

No errors or nothing much on traces as well. Collector Node configured as configurable service with collectionExpiry of 60 seconds.

Any suggestion how this can be tuned on high performing environment or alternate way to achieve this?

Am struggling to achieve this and help is really appreciated!!

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: You did not mention a HTTP Reply node. Are you using one?

Comment: yes am using HTTP Reply node to send some customized response.

Comment: You should describe the problem more accurately. Are you getting timeouts or are connections rejected? Where is the HTTP reply node in your flow? (The HTTP Input doesn't send any response to the clients by itself.) What is the purpose of the collector node, and how do you make sure you reply to each request? I believe you would need to reply before the collector node, as the collector node terminates the current flow transaction receiving the HTTP input message.

Comment: Am getting timeouts. Yes correct, HTTP reply node is before collector node, since collector node terminates the current  transaction. In the first compute node am splitting the single messages into chunks, run the mSet validation using RCD and send faulty message to error queue and then used collector node to collect messages using messages header (each full messages has unique value in the header, split --> Validate --> Collect) with collectionExpiry of 60 seconds

Comment: You question lack of details indeed. Can you please let us know the number of instances set on your message flow / http input ? Can you also provide the HTTPConnector configuration on your Integration Server (previously execution group) ? Same question for the HTTP listener ? Do you have any logs with errors other than the timeout ? What is the number of calls per second ? How much calls for one collect? In my opinion, it is probably the collect node waiting for messages in multiple collections and all the instances are already taken by other messages, but I cannot help without additional info